# Can chrome-cast be used without Wifi?

Tags: chromecast

To do a demo of my application to a group of persons, I need to cast my Android desktop to a TV.

Someone borrowed me a device that looks like [this one](https://www.amazon.fr/Chromecast-Incredibly-Useful-Guidelines-Smart/dp/1523903325/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1474546418&sr=8-3&keywords=chromecast) (probably not exactly the same version). However, it apparently requires a Wifi network to be used to cast some content.

Is there some other chromecast devices that would not require any Wifi connection to be used?

Comment: Have you installed the Google Cast app to see if that sees the Chromecast?  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app&hl=en    You said "it looks like this one" and linked to the newer Chromecast, to confirm, this IS a Chromecast (either 1st Gen or 2nd Gen)?

Comment: The link I provided looks like the chrome cast I used (unlike the one looking like a memory stick). I did install the app and was able to detect the chromecast device (seeing a code displayed on the TV). However, next step on Android device forced me to choose a Wifi network to connect to. No way I could skip this step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chromecast needs *some* sort of connection in order to receive the media to display.  Wi-Fi is the main option via a wireless router or a personal hot-spot.  Google also sells an [Ethernet adapter](https://store.google.com/product/ethernet_adapter_for_chromecast) that you can plug into your wired network.

Usually Chromecast requires Internet connectivity to function, but it is possible to trick it into working on a hot-spot that lacks Internet connectivity.  This work-around requires 2 Android devices for initial set-up, and the [LocalCast app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.stefanpledl.localcast&hl=en&gl=us). The steps are described [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dayDQ.jpg) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/comments/38sb3v/lpt_use_chromecast_without_internetmobile_data_by/crxfse8).

Quote:

> - Gather two devices
> - One must be an Android cell phone with mobile capability. The second can be any device that is capable of local media
> - open "settings" on cell phone
> - open "more networks"
> - select "mobile hotspot"
> - turn on "mobile hotspot"
> - go into "mobile hotspot" settings by selecting the 3 vertical dots in the upper-right corner
> - select configure hotspot
> - type in a name you would like to call your mobile hotspot network or leave the default name
> - scroll down to choose a password for this network
>
> Now we must switch the Wi-Fi network that the Chromecast is paired to.
>
> - ensure that the second device (the one you wish to cast from) is connected to the same network that the Chromecast is paired to (the
>     pairing was done when you first setup your Chromecast)
> - open the Chromecast app (if using iOS or Android) or open Chrome if using Linux, Windows, or MacOS
> - From the app choose the name of the Chromecast or from Chrome select the Chromecast icon in the upper-right of the screen, and then
>     choose the name of the Chromecast
> - Select "Wi-Fi"
> - Select the name of the network you are on (this will drop-down a menu with other networks)
> - Select the name of the mobile hotspot network you created and enter password
> - This will successfully switch the network that the Chromecast looks to connect to
>
> Now we will open LocalCast app and cast the video we desire. And
>   lastly we will go back to the cell phone and turn off "mobile data"
>   and leave on "mobile hotspot"

Comment: linked page to buy adapter says "This optional accessory lets you connect your Chromecast and Chromecast, 1st Generation directly to your router to create a fast and reliable connection for your Chromecast". Does that mean it does not work with Chromecast 2nd generation? You confirm Chromecast 2nd generation also needs a Wi-Fi connection?

Comment: @jpo38 It works with 2nd Gen Chromecast.

Comment: You mean the adaptor works? Or it works without Wifi?

Comment: The adapter works.

Comment: Thanx again for your help. As I have no Wifi, no network and no mobile data....I guess I have no solution (could not setup a Wifi network without activating my mobile data on my Nexus 6).

Comment: @jpo38 In that case Chromecast may not be the solution you are looking for.  Connecting your phone directly to a TV is possible, but only with phones that [support MHL](http://www.mhltech.org/devices.aspx?tid=1) and with a proper adapter cable.

Comment: Saw that...but my Motorola Nexus 6 is not listed here.....unfortunately ;-). Thanx for your help!

Comment: apparently, for devices not supporting MHL, SlimPort works (at leats for the Nexus 5. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

NO you need wifi. or create a hotspot with your phone and connect it to that

Comment: But this website http://www.alphr.com/google/google-chromecast/1002449/how-to-use-chromecast-without-wi-fi-making-the-most-of-google-s says "Using Chromecast without Wi-Fi is really quite simple because Google now allows you to cast locally stored content from your phone or laptop to Chromecast without a Wi-Fi connection. You can also mirror your device without Wi-Fi."

Comment: "create a hotspot with your phone" can I do that without enabling mobile data? With no SIM card for instance?

Comment: Yes, on Android you can.

Comment: Some carrier-locked phones are locked out of disabling mobile data while Wi-Fi hot-spot feature is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently ezCast allows to do that (chrome with no Wifi available), it setup its own Wifi network.

https://forum.iezvu.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=407